# Rotate <li> in <ul> using javascript?

Tags: javascript, rotation, gsap

I have arranged a list in circular order and I want to rotate it by holding the mouse. I am using `GreenSock` `JavaScript` plugin to rotate the `<div>`, but it is not rotating around its center and that is what I want.

The code is here.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>CryVault</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="ui/css/style.css" type="text/css">
        <script src="ui/js/TweenLite.min.js"></script>
        <script src="ui/js/Draggable.min.js"></script>
        <script src="ui/js/CSSPlugin.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div align="center">
            <ul class='circle-container'>
                <li>A</li>
                <li>B</li>
                <li>C</li>
                <li>D</li>
                <li>E</li>
                <li>F</li>
                <li>H</li>
                <li>I</li>
                <li>J</li>
                <li>K</li>
                <li>L</li>
                <li>M</li>
                <li>N</li>
                <li>O</li>
                <li>P</li>
                <li>Q</li>
                <li>R</li>
                <li>S</li>
                <li>T</li>
                <li>U</li>
                <li>V</li>
                <li>W</li>
                <li>X</li>
                <li>Y</li>
                <li>Z</li>
                <li>0</li>
                <li>1</li>
                <li>2</li>
                <li>3</li>
                <li>4</li>
                <li>5</li>
                <li>6</li>
                <li>7</li>
                <li>8</li>
                <li>9</li>
                <li>!</li>
                <li>@</li>
                <li>#</li>
                <li>$</li>
                <li>%</li>
                <li>^</li>
                <li>&</li>
                <li>*</li>
                <li>-</li>
                <li>_</li>
                <li>+</li>
                <li>=</li>

            </ul>
        </div>
        <script>            
            Draggable.create(".circle-container", {type: "rotation", throwProps: true});
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am new to `JavaScript` and have not any idea how does it work. Any help regarding this would be appreciated.

Here is a screenshot of the output.
[image]

Comment: [Ok! Click me](https://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/Utils/Draggable/create/)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your comments in @Dr.Roggia's answer, I think you want to rotate the characters around the center when you drag the mouse in circles. Some time ago I needed to do something like that and it can be done without using any library. I've adapted my code to your needs. I've used `CSS3 transforms` to modify the position of the characters:

```js
//---Vars
var container = document.getElementById("container"),
    offset = container.getBoundingClientRect(),
    elements = container.querySelectorAll("li"),
    radius = container.offsetWidth / 2,
    angle = (360 / elements.length) * Math.PI / 180,
    sangle = 0,
    eangle = 0,
    increment = 0;

//---Get the angle formed between the mouse and the center
function getAngle(x, y) {

  x = x - offset.left;
  y = y - offset.top;

  return Math.atan2(radius - y, radius - x);

}

//---Move elements
function moveElements() {

  var x = 0,
      y = 0,
      itemAngle = 0,
      transform = "";

  Array.prototype.forEach.call(elements, function(item, index) {

    itemAngle = index * angle + increment;
    x = radius + Math.cos(itemAngle) * radius;
    y = radius + Math.sin(itemAngle) * radius;
    transform = "translate(" + x + "px, " + y + "px)";

    item.style.msTransform = transform;
    item.style.webkitTransform = transform;
    item.style.MozTransform = transform;
    item.style.transform = transform;

  });

}

//---Start drag
function startDrag(evt) {

  sangle = getAngle(evt.pageX, evt.pageY);

  document.addEventListener("mousemove", moveDrag);
  document.addEventListener("mouseup", endDrag);

}

//---Move drag
function moveDrag(evt) {

  increment = getAngle(evt.pageX, evt.pageY) - sangle + eangle;

  moveElements();

}

//---End drag
function endDrag(evt) {

  eangle = increment;

  document.removeEventListener("mousemove", moveDrag);
  document.removeEventListener("mouseup", endDrag);

}

//---Start drag event
document.addEventListener("mousedown", startDrag);

//---Set the initial position
moveElements();
```

```css
#container {
  cursor: default;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
}

#container span {
  color: #666;
  display: block;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 12px;
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.circle {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.circle li {
  color: #666;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  list-style-type: none;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <span>Drag in circle</span>
  <ul class='circle'>
    <li>A</li>
    <li>B</li>
    <li>C</li>
    <li>D</li>
    <li>E</li>
    <li>F</li>
    <li>H</li>
    <li>I</li>
    <li>J</li>
    <li>K</li>
    <li>L</li>
    <li>M</li>
    <li>N</li>
    <li>O</li>
    <li>P</li>
    <li>Q</li>
    <li>R</li>
    <li>S</li>
    <li>T</li>
    <li>U</li>
    <li>V</li>
    <li>W</li>
    <li>X</li>
    <li>Y</li>
    <li>Z</li>
    <li>0</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>7</li>
    <li>8</li>
    <li>9</li>
    <li>!</li>
    <li>@</li>
    <li>#</li>
    <li>$</li>
    <li>%</li>
    <li>^</li>
    <li>&</li>
    <li>*</li>
    <li>-</li>
    <li>_</li>
    <li>+</li>
    <li>=</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Here you have a `Codepen` with the same code of the above snippet:

http://codepen.io/elchininet/pen/WRvZRx

**EDIT:**

A little fork from the previous `Codepen` working with `TouchEvents`:

http://codepen.io/elchininet/pen/rjYgBE

Answer (score -1):

If I'm understanding correctly, you can rotate around the left side by using `transformOrigin: "left 50%"`. To rotate around the center, use `50% 50%`. e.g.

```
TweenLite.to(element, 2, {rotation:90, transformOrigin:"left 50%"});
```

To put the animation while the button is clicked, you have to use the `mousedown` function:

```
$('#Clicker').mousedown(function () {
    TweenLite.to(element, 2, {rotation: 90, transformOrigin: "left 50% 50%"});
    timeout = setInterval(function () {
        TweenLite.to(element, 2, {rotation: 90, transformOrigin: "left 50% 50%"});
    }, 500);
    return false;
});

$('#Clicker').mouseup(function () {
    clearInterval(timeout);
    return false;
});

$('#Clicker').mouseout(function () {
    clearInterval(timeout);
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Sir I have posted an image please check the updated question. I want to rotate those characters in circle in circular way.

Comment: I want them to rotate on drag.